# Why is Google not indexing my thumbnails?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-image-search

Hello Webmaster community!

I recently began a new job and have been making some adjustments to a very old and very cluttered website. The idea is to eventually rebuild from the ground up, however, for the time being I have to make this current site as SEO friendly as I can.

My site seems to be indexing fine after I submitted fresh site maps, and a lot of the images on the site's product pages are showing up, but I noticed today that none of the thumbnails are being picked up by Google at all.

I am very new to SEO and web design and I need help understanding why my images are not being indexed into google correctly? My only thought is that it something to do with the thumbnail images being in a folder, while the full size images reside in the same folder as the .htm file they are associated with.

Overall I need some guidance on what the issue is, how to fix it and measures I can take to prevent it in the future.

I hope I explained this well enough, please help me out!

Thank you to all!

I hope this makes

Comment: Small images are low quality and Google doesn't index then.